# Bounding box realignment from CoreML object detection

Tags: swift, arkit, coreml

I am currently trying to render a bounding boxes inside a UIView, however currently I'm facing the issue that there is a misalignment in the X axis when trying to render the box as can be seen in the screenshot below.
[image]
When the object is on the left of the view the misalignment will be on the right like seen in the image. However when the object is on the right the misalignment will be to the left. The misalignment increases the further it gets to the edge of the screen.

Currently are use ARKit to capture the current frame as a pixel buffer.

```
let pixelBuffer = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.capturedImage
// Capture current device orientation
let orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(rawValue: UIDevice.current.exifOrientation)
let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: orientation)
```

Additionally additionally my CoroML vision request looks as follows

```
findObjectRequest = VNCoreMLRequest(model: visionModel, completionHandler: visionRequestDidComplete)
findObjectRequest?.imageCropAndScaleOption = .scaleFit
```

I then try to reschedule the normalised bounding box to image Space like this:

```
public func scaleImageForCameraOutput(predictionRect finderrItem: FinderrItem, viewRect: CGRect) -> FinderrItem {
    let scale = CGAffineTransform.identity.scaledBy(x: viewRect.width, y: viewRect.height)
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1).translatedBy(x: 0, y: -1)
    let bgRect = finderrItem.box.applying(transform).applying(scale)
    finderrItem.box = bgRect
    return finderrItem
}
```

I also tried to follow the Apple developer documentation and using the API code to re-scale the banding boxes as follows

```
 let newBox = VNImageRectForNormalizedRect(
               boundingBox,
                Int(self.sceneView.bounds.width),
                Int(self.sceneView.bounds.height))
```

However this still has the same issue with another issue that the y-axis is now inverted.

Does anyone know why I'm having this problem I've been stuck on it for quite awhile now and can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Your `scaleImageForCameraOutput` is not taking into account the scaling that ARKit performs when it displays the camera frame.

Comment: How would I go about taking that scaling into account?

Comment: You need to figure out where (0,0) and (W,H) for the video image really are. These points do not correspond to the origin and size of the view that displays the video image. I don't know if there is an API that ARKit gives you for this but you can also do it by hand. If the video frame is 720x1280, parts of the video will be outside the sides of the screen, so (0,0) in the video frame will be a negative value relative to the views (0,0).